# Table of contents missing its title in scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, scrbook

For the following document, I am having trouble understanding why the Table of Contents is missing its title. I've also noticed that when I add \frontmatter, all chapter titles disappear and the chapter numbers become messed up (chapter one seemingly becomes chapter zero). How can I fix this so that the table of contents has a title with the same style as each of the chapters? As a side question, is there a way to alter the page headers so as to omit the chapter numbers? So for example, '1. Introduction' would simply become 'Introduction'.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm,top=4.15cm,bottom=4.27cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc,chngcntr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter \quad \MakeUppercase{#1}}{.5em}{\vspace{.5ex}}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{-12.5pt}{19.5pt}


\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\bfseries}
{\S\ \thesection \enskip}
{\fontdimen2\font}
{#1}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\lohead[]{\headmark}
\rehead{Title}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\footnotesize}% or "\footnotesize" depending on fonts
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark[chapter]{}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum
\newpage 
More 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redefinition of the chapter format using `\titleformat` results in the issue. This also happens if you replace `scrbook` by the standard class `book`.

But it is also not recommended to use `titletoc` and `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class. So here is a suggestion using KOMA-Script commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,numbers=enddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm,top=4.15cm,bottom=4.27cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.25em,
  afterskip=19.5pt,
]{chapter}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}\vspace{-.25em}\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily\Large}
\setkomafont{section}{\rmfamily\normalsize}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\S\ \thesection\autodot\enskip}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\lohead{\headmark}
\rehead{Title}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\footnotesize}% or "\footnotesize" depending on fonts
\automark[chapter]{}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

To remove the chapter number in page headers add

```
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}
```

to the preamble.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the chapter title is set in the “if numbered chapter” part (third mandatory argument to `\titleformat`, so nothing appears in unnumbered chapters such as the table of contents.

The solution is to use `block` format.

In the code below, I changed `scrbook` into `book`, because Komascript classes don't like `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  top=4.15cm,
  bottom=4.27cm,
  headheight=14.5pt,% <--- don't forget
  showframe,
]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with newer LaTeX
%\usepackage{chngcntr} % not needed with newer LaTeX
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  [\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {-12.5pt}
  {19.5pt}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\bfseries}
  {\S\ \thesection}
  {\fontdimen2\font}
  {}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\lohead[]{\scshape\headmark}
\rehead{Title}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum
\clearpage 

More 

\end{document}
```

[image]